# getting the "this" that a function's caller was called with in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the `this` that a function's `caller` was called with in JavaScript *without* passing `this` to the arguments in a way which supports IE as well as Firefox/Chrome et al?

For example:

```
var ob = {
    callme: function() {
        doSomething();
    }
}
ob.callme();

function doSomething() {
    alert(doSomething.caller.this === ob); // how can I find the `this` that 
                                           // `callme` was called with 
                                           // (`ob` in this case) without 
                                           // passing `this` to `doSomething`?
}
```

I'm starting to suspect it's not, but I thought I may as well ask as it'd make my code much shorter and easier to read.

Comment: @stagas: `__parent__` is a Mozilla extension, which actually works well only on Rhino, it's a way to expose the *variable object* (the top object of the scope chain of a function), where variables, arguments and function declarations are bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the closest I can think, without *technically* passing the value as an *argument*, would be to set the `this` value of the `doSomething` function.

Since the `doSomething` function is not bound to any object, by default, if you call it like `doSomething();` the `this` value inside it will refer to the Global object, and that's normally not too useful...

For example:

```
var ob = {
  callme: function () {
    doSomething.call(this); // bind the `this` value of `doSomething`
  }
};

function doSomething () {
  alert(this === ob); // use the bound `this` value
}

ob.callme();
```

Comment: It does indeed seem to look like it's not possible to do it without passing it somehow. Thanks anyway though, I'll mark this as accepted if no-one solves it later today :-)