# arguments.callee.caller... how to get 'this' reference of a caller object?

Tags: javascript

I have a configuration object which may container scope property and may not and I pass it to my function. This function creates some callback functions and applies 'scope' property to them. I want to force this function to provide the scope even if it is not actually specified - to get 'this' reference of a caller, something like this:

```
function someFunc (config)
{
  var scope = config.scope ? config.scope : arguments.callee.caller... (?);
  config.preAction.apply(scope);
}
```

Is it actually possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the "this" that a function's caller was called with in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941197/getting-the-this-that-a-functions-caller-was-called-with-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your response but actually in the topic you link people did not solve that problem without explicit passing of 'this' reference to the function. Seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you assumed in your comment, the answer is that it is impossible. JavaScript is simply not introspective enough.